# SOQL query to traverse several levels on Task

Tags: salesforce, soql, apex-code

I'm trying to write some apex code using this query and not getting anywhere:

```
List<Task> tasks = [SELECT id, whatid, who.account.parent.name FROM task WHERE who.account.parent.name LIKE 'Procter%'];
```

I'm not surprised this doesn't work, but can't seem to find documentation anywhere that explains how I would go about this.  Does anyone have any idea?  I'm trying to get all tasks linked to a contact linked to an account with a parent account of "procter and gamble"...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the options to "go up" in the mixed fields (the ones where Lookup goes to multiple objects like WhatId going to Account or Opportunity) are very limited. I was able to write "WHERE what.name LIKE 'Procter%' but not "WHERE what.parent.name LIKE 'Procter%'".

By the way I think it should be WhatId and not the WhoId (check out the Validation Rule editor for Tasks, try to insert fields "Contact/Lead ID" and "Opportunity/Account ID"). You will also see that you can't "go up" (or in case of this editor - "go right") on these fields while for some other fields you can explore the relation like for "CreatedBy.UserRole.Name".

Can you try this subquery instead?

```
[SELECT id, whatid FROM task WHERE whatid IN (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Parent.Name LIKE 'United%')]
```

Answer (score 1):

WhatId and WhoID are polymorphic fields, so these fields do not support traversing multiple levels.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for hierarchal traversing, in my case i had to select the lead information associated with a task. What I had to do was first query for a list of tasks, then query for a list of leads based off those tasks, then use a wrapper class to combine the two lists into a custom object and display the object accordingly using visualforce. The wrapper class was certainly my answer to the equation since it seems you are in fact unable to query directly using the Who.Id.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The AccountID field on Tasks is populated by SF automatically for Contacts.  Obviously, it is blank for Leads.  So, if you want to get Account data you can just do something like this:

SELECT ID, Who.FirstName, Who.LastName, Account.Parent.Name FROM Task WHERE WhoID = '00Q12SDFUUALDLKJF'

Obviously, Account.Parent.Name is blank for Leads.